# sshd config: Allow connections only from within the same private network

Tags: openssh, sshd

I would like to configure sshd so that any user inside the same private network is accepted, but everyone else is denied.

Example: My IP address is 192.168.1.159, so anyone inside the network 192.168.1.0 should be allowed.

**Background:**

Currently I am configuring an embedded device image, and thought of adding this as a small additional security measure. The image will run on devices in different locations.
The IP address is going to be assigned via DHCP, and each system might be attached to differently configured private networks (like 10.0.1.0, 192.168.100.0, ...).

So I guess, ideally, what I would have wanted is:

```
DenyUsers *
Match Address OWN_DEVICE_ADDRESS/24
    AllowUsers *
```

Reading the manpage of `sshd_config` however I could not find such a possibility.

So I ended up with the idea of accepting all users with private network ip v4 addresses and appended the following to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match Address 192.168.0.0/16,172.16.0.0/12,10.0.0.0/8
        AllowUsers *

DenyUsers *
```

Testing this (output via `systemctl status sshd`) however shows that even though I am in the same network,  the `DenyUsers` rule is still overriding:

```
Apr 25 23:37:43 host sshd[27733]: User test from 192.168.1.166 not allowed because listed in DenyUsers *
```

So I guess I failed to understand the concept of `DenyUsers`. Could you guys help me out please?

Comment: Why not just use iptables to block the connections?

Comment: I've not tried this variant, but I imagine dropping the MatxhAddress and DenyUsers lines and just having an "AllowUsers *@192.168.9.0/16 *@172.16.0.0.16" would work. Simple.

Comment: @davidgo - Thanks for suggesting `iptables` . I will look into that. But for now your second suggestion works. Brilliant! Thank you.  The following line in the config does the job `AllowUsers *@172.16.0.0/12 *@10.0.0.0/8 *@192.168.0.0/16`. If you make it an answer I will gladly accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding following line to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, only users with a private network ip v4 address are accepted:

```
AllowUsers *@172.16.0.0/12 *@10.0.0.0/8 *@192.168.0.0/16
```

The comment by @davidgo solved it (I am putting it up as an answer for better visibility):

> I've not tried this variant, but I imagine dropping the MatxhAddress and DenyUsers 
>   lines and just having an "AllowUsers *@192.168.9.0/16 *@172.16.0.0.16" would work.  Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Is this OpenSSH? If you want to block everyone from the outside, then I would suggest to modify these lines:

```
Port 22
AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
```

to match your needs. Especially the last one seems to be relevant for your situation.

Comment: Not really, as the server can be reached from any network via destination address that isn't an element of it. (It's really just a matter of routes on the client, and maybe ARP.) So some sort of (interface based) firewalling would be the solution.